# Display different category template if custom field is checked

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am a big fan of Advanced Custom Field by Elliot Condon
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

This is what I am trying to chive without success so far:

I have a website with posts and **archive.php** displays my archive posts page.
Now, I would like to display different template for certain categories.
I don't have the name of the category which I want to display this template for, I would like to do it dynamically so whenever my user creates a post he can choose a special custom field from within that post (true, false preferably) e.g - this post belongs to "projects" category and if the checkbox is checked - **archive.php** will call different layout using include file.

if this option is unchecked. **archive.php** show the regular template

I was thinking about simply creating a custom field called "**is_project_category**"
and assign it to a post page but when I tried to use it in archive.php it didn't work at all

I used this code:

```
<?php
 $is_projects_category = get_field('is_projects_category');
 if('is_projects_category' == true){?>

// include the special category template for projects

<?php } else{ ?>

// display normal archive template

<?php } ?>
```

it didn't work..

any idea how to use it outside the loop of **single.php** and show it in archive.php (or anywhere in the theme)?

Thanks

Comment: How did you "try to use it"? Post your code please.

Comment: I edited my question with the code.

Comment: This looks like a PHP syntax error. You need to check against the variable you created and not against a static string-- `if($is_projects_category == true){`

Comment: You were right about the PHP error. however, I fixed it and it's still not working. the Custom Field is assigned to a category. maybe Custom Field is not working on archive.php? is it possible?

Comment: Please update the code in the question with your most recent version.

Comment: Questions dependent upon third party plugins are off-topic, as are pure PHP questions. I strongly suspect that this is one of the two but just for fun add `var_dump($is_projects_category);` and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this recently with the following code in archive.php

```
add_action('genesis_loop', 'blah_search_results');
function blah_search_results() { 
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  if (is_category('in-the-news')) {
   // Get article URL
   $article_url = get_field('original_article_url');
   // rest of theme goes here
  }
 endwhile;
}
```